# Unable to use Ember data with JSONAPI and fragments to support nested JSON data

Tags: serialization, ember.js, ember-data, json-api

## Overview

I'm using Ember data and have a JSONAPI. Everything works fine until I have a more complex object (let's say an invoice for a generic concept) with an array of items called lineEntries. The line entries are not mapped directly to a table so need to be stored as raw JSON object data. The line entry model also contains default and computed values. I wish to store the list data as a JSON object and then when loaded back from the store that I can manipulate it as normal in Ember as an array of my model.

## What I've tried

I've looked at and tried several approaches, the best appear to be (open to suggestions here!):

### Fragments

Replace problem models with fragments

I've tried making the line entry model a fragment and then referencing the fragment on the invoice model as a fragmentArray. Line entries add to the array as normal but default values don't work (should they?). It creates the object and I can store it in the backend but when I return it, it fails with either a normalisation issue or a serialiser issue. Can anyone state the format the data be returned in? It's confusing as normalising the data seems to require JSONAPI but the fragment requires JSON serialiser. I've tried several combinations but no luck so far. My line entries don't have actual ids as the data is saved and loaded as a block. Is this an issue?

### DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin

Although not supported in JSONAPI, it sounds possible to use JSONAPI and then switch to JSONSerializer or RESTSerializer for the problem models. If this is possible could someone give me a working example and the JSON format that should be returned by the API? I have header authorisation and other such data so would I still be able to set this at the application level for all request not using my JSONAPI?

### Ember-data-save-relationships

I found an add on [here](https://emberigniter.com/saving-models-relationships-json-api/) that provides an add on to do this. It seems more involved than the other approaches but when I've tried this I can send the data up by setting a the data as embedded. Great! But although it saves it doesn't unwrap it correct and I'm back with the same issues.

### Custom serialiser

Replace the models serialiser with something that takes the data and sends it as plain JSON data and then deserialises back into something Ember can use. This sounds similar to the above but I do the heavy lifting. The only reason to do this is because all examples for the above solutions are quite light and don't really show how to set this up with an actual JSONAPI set up that would need it.

## Where I am and what I need

Basically all approaches lead to saving the JSON fine but the return JSON from the server not being the correct format or the deserialisation failing but it's unclear what it should be or what needs to change without breaking the existing JSONAPI models that work fine.

If anyone know the format for return API data it may resolve this. I've tried JSONAPI with lineEntries returning the same format as it saved. I've tried placing relationship sections like the add on suggested and I've also tried placing relationship only data against the entries and an include section with all the references. Any help on this would be great as I've learned a lot through this but deadlines a looming and I can't see a viable solution that doesn't break as much as it fixes.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for return format for relational data from the API server you need to make sure of the following:

1. Make sure the relationship is defined in the ember model
2. Return all successes with a status code of 200

From there you need to make sure you return relational data correctly. If you've set the ember model for the relationship to `{async: true}` you need only return the id of the relational model - which should also be defined in ember. If you do not set `{async: true}`, ember expects all relational data to be included.

3. return data with relationships in JSON API specification

### Example:

`models\unicorn.js` in ember:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  user: DS.belongsTo('user', {async: true}),
  staticrace: DS.belongsTo('staticrace',{async: true}),
  unicornName: DS.attr('string'),
  unicornLevel: DS.attr('number'),
  experience: DS.attr('number'),
  hatchesAt: DS.attr('number'),
  isHatched: DS.attr('boolean'),
  raceEndsAt: DS.attr('number'),
  isRacing: DS.attr('boolean'),
});
```

in `routes\unicorns.js` on the api server on `GET/:id`:

```
var jsonObject = {
  "data": {
    "type": "unicorn",
    "id": unicorn.dataValues.id,
    "attributes": {
      "unicorn-name" : unicorn.dataValues.unicornName,
      "unicorn-level" : unicorn.dataValues.unicornLevel,
      "experience" : unicorn.dataValues.experience,
      "hatches-at" : unicorn.dataValues.hatchesAt,
      "is-hatched" : unicorn.dataValues.isHatched,
      "raceEndsAt" : unicorn.dataValues.raceEndsAt,
      "isRacing" : unicorn.dataValues.isRacing
    },
    "relationships": {
      "staticrace": {
        "data": {"type": "staticrace", "id" : unicorn.dataValues.staticRaceId}
      },
      "user":{
        "data": {"type": "user", "id" : unicorn.dataValues.userId}
      }
    }
  }
}
res.status(200).json(jsonObject);
```

In ember, you can call this by chaining model functions. For example when this unicorn goes to race in `controllers\unicornracer.js`:

```
raceUnicorn() {
  if (this.get('unicornId') === '') {return false}
  else {
  return this.store.findRecord('unicorn', this.get('unicornId', { backgroundReload: false})).then(unicorn => {
    return this.store.findRecord('staticrace', this.get('raceId')).then(staticrace => {
      if (unicorn.getProperties('unicornLevel').unicornLevel >= staticrace.getProperties('raceMinimumLevel').raceMinimumLevel) {
        unicorn.set('isRacing', true);
        unicorn.set('staticrace', staticrace);
        unicorn.set('raceEndsAt', Math.floor(Date.now()/1000) + staticrace.get('duration'))
        this.set('unicornId', '');
        return unicorn.save();
      }
      else {return false;}
    });
  });
  }
}
```

The above code sends a PATCH to the api server route `unicorns/:id`

Final note about `GET`,`POST`,`DELETE`,`PATCH`:

`GET` assumes you are getting ALL of the information associated with a model (the example above shows a `GET` response). This is associated with model.findRecord (GET/:id)(expects one record), model.findAll(GET/)(expects an array of records), model.query(GET/?query=&string=)(expects an array of records), model.queryRecord(GET/?query=&string=)(expects one record)

`POST` assumes you at least return at least what you `POST` to the api server from ember , but can also return additional information you created on the apiServer side such as createdAt dates. If the data returned is different from what you used to create the model, it'll update the created model with the returned information. This is associated with model.createRecord(POST/)(expects one record).

`DELETE` assumes you return the type, and the id of the deleted object, not data or relationships. This is associated with model.deleteRecord(DELETE/:id)(expects one record).

`PATCH` assumes you return at least what information was changed. If you only change one field, for instance in my `unicorn` model, the `unicornName`, it would only PATCH the following:

```
{
  data: {
    "type":"unicorn",
    "id": req.params.id,
    "attributes": {
      "unicorn-name" : "This is a new name!"
    }
  }
}
```

So it only expects a returned response of at least that, but like `POST`, you can return other changed items!

I hope this answers your questions about the JSON API adapter. Most of this information was originally gleamed by reading over the specification at http://jsonapi.org/format/ and the ember implementation documentation at https://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONAPIAdapter.html

Comment: Firstly, thanks for the detailed response. I already had standard responses working so the issue is specific to relationships where the child model is not mapped to a resource. It was useful to see the same format for the data so I was able to focus on other areas. I've found so far that I can return the relationship and just type and id and then "include" after the data attribute a list of included entries that don't actually exist outside the child model. Not ideal but it is getting me part there. How have you managed that? Your examples show relationships but no data against them.

Comment: The {async:true} i included at the top of the answer means once ember gets those record id's back, it'll query the API server for those related records - meaning i don't have to include the data (the way you seem to be doing it). I reread what you are trying to do and without example code of where it is failing is hard to pinpoint.

Comment: Maybe my question is unclear. The issue is nothing to do with async. This is is a one attribute in a model with child relationships being stored as a single entry in non-relational database at the backend. Ember can't query this as they represent elements inside a single column and have no API entry point. Embedded record mix in tackles this for non-JSONAPI in Ember and fragments also do something similar. I'm close to resolving this so I'll update the question and provide an answer if no one chips in before!

Comment: Hi Walter, I'm fighting some similar issues over here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44713406/action-cables-nested-json-attributes-and-jsonapi

Let me know if you find/found a solution!