# Action Cables, nested JSON attributes and JSONAPI

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, json-api

I have a fairly specific problem that I was hoping one of you really intelligent folk might know a solution for (or even a workaround at this stage)

Specifically, I'm dealing with *action cables, nested JSON, and the JSONAPI*.

I have an `asset` model, which has some attributes like `name`, `desc` etc. but it also has an attribute called `state` which is a complex nested JSON object.

```
// app/models/asset.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
    // Attributes
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    desc: DS.attr('string'),
    state: DS.attr(),
    lastSeen: DS.attr('date'),
});
```

When anything on the asset changes in the backend, it is pushed down the cable to Ember, where it does a `pushPayload(data)`, the payload looks like this;

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": "5",
        "type": "assets",
        "attributes": {
            "asset_id": "962ABC",
            "name": "962 ABC",
            "desc": "Test Vehicle",
            "activation_status": "active",
            "state": {
                "avl": {
                    "longitude": 152.9475426,
                    "reported_at": "2017-06-22T21:59:52Z"
                },
                "dfm": {
                    "in_alarm": false,
                    "reported_at": "2017-06-21T05:46:57Z",
                    "sensitivity": "normal",
                    "voice_prompt": false,
                    "driver_detected": true,
                },
                "tpms": {
                    "system_desc": "123ABC",
                    "system_type": "123_abc"
                }
            },
            "last_seen": "2017-06-22T21:59:54.000Z"
        },
        "relationships": {
            "company": {
                "data": {
                    "id": "1",
                    "type": "companies"
                }
            },
            "events": {
                "links": {
                    "related": "/events/?asset_id=5"
                }
            },
            "messages": {
                "links": {
                    "related": "/messages/?asset_id=5"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This all works fine and dandy, updates to the asset & state are displayed as they happen thanks to the cable, and `state` is read only so I don't have to worry about saving anything. HOWEVER, I have noticed that when any single attribute on `state` changes in the backend, the entire asset is pushed down from the backend (this should be fine), and then this fires the observer for `state` and also all observers for `state` descendants - whereas I need it to **only fire the observer for the state attribute that changed**.

I have tried a number of things and each seemed to either not work at all, or still continue to update state in a way that fired off all state observers.

What I have tried;

1. ember-model-data-fragments (while it should work, I think the way that the action cable pushes the data must subvert this?)
2. embedded records (requires an ID for state, not currently compatible with JSONAPI)
3. raw json transform (making the json into ember objects, didn't seem to help)

Can anyone suggest a strategy or solution for me to try? I've spent nearly 2 days on this problem.. I would even settle for just splitting it up between `avl`/`tpms`/`dfm`, as long as when an attribute in one of those sections is changed, it doesn't notify properties from the other 2 sections.

Thanks

Comment: how many instances of the top level model would you be handling updates for at once? more than one? i'd stay away from embedded records and model fragments. i've used them both and have the scars to prove it. maybe we can bounce some ideas off of each other. to start with i'd need to know more about the specific scenario you're trying to solve for. what i'm driving toward is maybe doing something in a service that keeps a copy of the old data and compares it to the new data. there are also ember data methods you can hook into that will fire if an attribute will change. we can look at those

Comment: but those ember data methods likely won't work with a complex nested object. we could go the service route or we could cache the old data on the model itself to compare against when the new data comes in

Comment: you could probably hook into the 'didLoad' event on the model to do the comparison

Comment: For the top level model (asset), there will probably be about 500 different assets throughout the application, each receiving state updates anywhere from several times a second (worst case) to once every 30 minutes (best case). Most likely scenario would be closer to once every minute.

Comment: I do have access to the backend API, so if it helps, I could do something like only send down the state attributes that have changed (for example). The JSON payload I provided above is a very cut down example, but it will have a timestamp (`reported_at`) at every level of the nested state indicating the last time that level or its descendants changed. This may also help in the data comparisons if we go with that.

Comment: It is also worth noting that the `tpms` state object will actually be very complex, having several arrays etc - I don't need it to fire observers on individual properties here, it can be a `tpms`-wide observer, as long as changes to any attributes in the `tpms` state object don't fire observers on properties from `avl` or `dfm` (and vise versa).

Comment: I guess in terms of the specific scenario I'm trying to solve for... there are many assets that we are tracking, that each have several types of sensors (`avl`, `dfm`, `tpms`, etc.) which report data to the backend. These sensors report different information at different times, and the backend keeps a `state` for each asset, which always contains the latest data about the asset but is not saved to a table or anything like that (so no id's).

Comment: The state data is used to display lots of dynamic information on the front end (graphs, svg drawings, images). The problem we are trying to solve is  that each time anything at all in the state changes (which is frequent) all of these sections think their specific sensor data has changed, causing them to redraw/etc when actually it was probably an unrelated attribute from a different sensor that changed. For example, I don't need the `dfm` images updating when the location changes in the `avl` state object.